# What does "go for adds" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does the phrase "go for adds" mean?

I ran across it here:
http://www.countrystandardtime.com/news/newsitem.asp?xid=7772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Goes for adds](http://www.fairtradeservices.com/656/)" means that a song/record/single will be **added** to a radio station playlist on a certain date. It is mainly a music industry term reserved for newly or pre-released songs.

> New Radio Single “A Million Miles Away” Goes For Adds Now
>   [...] Today, Hawk Nelson is releasing their newest single from Made, “A
>   Million Miles Away” to radio.

This is one of the earliest documented usage of [**adds**](http://www.americanradiohistory.com/Archive-RandR/2000s/2001/RR-2001-04-27a.pdf) I found on Google, dated 2001

[image]

EDIT
On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:WikiProject_Songs/Archive_7#.27Radio_ONLY.27_singles...Propose_infobox_Radio_single_if_the_industry_would_support_this.) there seemed to be a debate as to whether a song that *goes for adds* is synonymous with *release*.

> I recognize in this section header that the industry must prevail
>   "Radio single if the industry would support this." However the
>   industry does NOT support calling Radio dates a 'release' either, so
>   how can we? They go through great pains to avoid it, which is why I
>   strive to do the same. They call it "Radio add date", "going for adds"
>   etc but NOT 'release'.

A wiki contributor later adds (sorry, couldn't resist)

> I reiterate that there are many singles that are released worldwide
>   digitally and/or physically, however in the US the labels don't
>   bother, and just send them to radio because they expect people will
>   purchase them as album tracks from digital retailers. I have a feeling
>   that **in the US radio adds are a bigger deal than in the rest of the
>   world**; there are several US webpages that document radio adds. I don't
>   really have a problem with not calling radio adds a "release", but I
>   do believe that they denote a single (in the US, at least)